# How to solve TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the following code, but it fails with the error message `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` at line `if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):`. The object `json_string` is obtained with `json_string = json.loads(text)`

```
def getField(dt,json_string):

    fields = {k['type']: ((k['start-month'],k['start-day']),(k['end-month'],k['end-day'])) for k in json_string}

    field = "NA"    
    for t, ranges in fields.items():
        for start, end in ranges:
            if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):
                field = t
                break
        if field != "NA":
            break
    return field 

text = '''[{"end-day":31,"end-month":5,"type":"T1","start-day":10,"start-month":1},{"end-day":9,"end-month":1,"type":"T2","start-day":1,"start-month":9},{"end-day":30,"end-month":9,"type":"T3","start-day":1,"start-month":6}]'''

json_string = json.loads(text)
dt = datetime.strptime("2015-03-12 11:00:00.0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

getField(dt,json_string)
```

**UPDATE:**

The content of `fields`:

```
{u'Type1': ((6, 1), (9, 30)),
 u'Type2': ((1, 10), (5, 31)),
 u'Type3': ((9, 1), (1, 9))}
```

Comment: It means one of the things you're trying to use `[]` on is an `int`, not a list or tuple, or whatever you expect it to be.

Comment: `start` and `end` are integers.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, I understand it, but why is it integer, if I have this structure for each range `((...),(...))`. I expected that `start` and `end ` both are `(...,...)`. Please see my update.

Comment: Debug it with `pdb` and see what's the content of `start`, `end`  and `ranges` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: You have essentially `for (start,end) in ((6, 1), (9, 30))`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Ah, I see. Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this:

```
if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1])
```

it is clear that you are expecting `start` to be a tuple containing month and day. But if I do this:

```
for t, ranges in fields.items():
    for start, end in ranges:
        print (f"start={start} end={end}")
```

I get:

```
start=6 end=1
start=9 end=30
start=1 end=10
start=5 end=31
start=9 end=1
start=1 end=9
```

Now you can see where the error message is coming from. `start[0]` means `6[0]`. Do this instead:

```
for t, (start,end) in fields.items():
```

Then `start` and `end` will be the month/day tuples you expect.

Answer (score 1):

What you ought to be doing is

```
start, end = ranges
```

rather than looping through them. Also, `ranges` isn't a good name, something like `date_pairs` might make more sense.

What you have in `ranges` is a sequence of pairs (2 of them, to be exact). Thus the `for` loop will iterate twice - once for the pair of ints representing the start date, and once for the pair of ints representing the end date. In each iteration, `start` and `end` will be integers, not pairs, so you can't index them.